# How to extract part of filename in a folder in Linux

Tags: linux

I have list of Jars, around 20 in a folder with versions. (EG: abc.defg-hij-1.0.10.jar). I want write all these jar file names to a file by removing the version and extension. (Expected : abc.defg-hij).

I am using this command:

```
printf '%s\n' *.jar> /opt/Test_hemachandar/test_bin/remote.txt
```

This gives me list of all the jar file names to remote.txt file, where I want to remove the version and extension.

Comment: why is that negative voting for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the version and extension, you can pipe the names through `sed`:

```
… | sed 's/[-0-9.]*jar$//' >/opt/Test_hemachandar/test_bin/remote.txt
```